# Add a Network Location to a Host with multiple shares

Tags: mapping, share

I have 3 shares on my server: 2 shared folders on drive D: and the entire V: drive. On another network PC I can open a File Explorer window and enter the the host name in the address bar, i.e. "\Server", and I can see all three shares. I would like to "Add a network location" that points to "\Server". However, I can not "Add a network location" (or map a network drive) without both the host and share names. I can create a short cut to the host, say on the Desktop (or any other location for that matter), that works as desired, but I can't create a shortcut in "This PC".

I would really rather have a single icon in "This PC" that connects to the host with the shares than create three network locations, one for each share. Is this possible?

Comment: I am guessing you never came up with a solution for this, as there is no answer.

I am pretty sure there isn't a way to do this. You can only map to a Samba share, as far as I know. I also just have a shortcut pinned to the hostname in "Quick Access"

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you never came up with a solution for this, as there is no answer.

I am pretty sure there isn't a way to do this. You can only map to a Samba share, as far as I know. I also just have a shortcut pinned to the hostname in "Quick Access"

If there is, I'd love to know!